# ajax is not fetching session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have sending an ajax request but the session is not working there Here is my jquery code

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'practice3.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {id: ids},
  success: function (response) {
    if (response == 1) {
      //$('.cart-items').html(response);
      alert('Add');
    } else if (respone == 0) {
      location.replace('loginregister.php');
    }
  },
});
```

Dont Get confused with id this is the data i was sending in ajax but first i wanted to check is session is working or not but didnt response anything and yes xhr status is 200 and here is my ajax code

```php
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
} 
?>
```

Please anyone help me out

Comment: `if(respone == 0)` is a typo, if that helps

Comment: that doesn't matter because its parameter name we can name it anything

Comment: And also more importantly you've started an output buffer, so that PHP will not output any content, but you haven't flushed it (the time when it finally sends the output). There seems to be no benefit here to output buffering though, so you can probably just remove the ob_start() command

Comment: it does matter because `respone` isn't the same as `response`, so `respone` won't have any value. It's a typing error not a naming problem. Please always double-check your work for this kind of thing! And use an IDE which helps you by suggesting auto-completes for variable names

Comment: sorry i misunderstood you you were right i written wrong

Comment: ok so is it working as you wanted now?